# Make dropdown selected using $_POST value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dropdown menu like this

```
    <form method="post">
            Filter by state:
            <select name="state" id="state">

                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option><option value="Other">Other</option>
                <input type="submit" id="statefilt" name="statefilt" onclick="" value="Submit" />
            </select>
        </form>
```

When the page is reloaded I get the $_POST to be

```
Array ([state]=>AL [statefilt]=>Submit)
```

Is there a way to use the `$_POST['state']` and make that the selected option if the value is not empty?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `selected` attribute when the `$_POST` value is same as `<option>` value.

And, `<input type="submit" id="statefilt" name="statefilt" onclick="" value="Submit" />` is wrong inside `<select></select>`

```
<form method="post">
  Filter by state:
  <select name="state" id="state">
      <option value="" <?if($_POST['state'] == ""){echo "selected";}?>></option>
      <option value="AL" <?if($_POST['state'] == "AL"){echo "selected";}?>>Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK" <?if($_POST['state'] == "AK"){echo "selected";}?>>Alaska</option>
      <option value="AZ" <?if($_POST['state'] == "AZ"){echo "selected";}?>>Arizona</option>
      <option value="AR" <?if($_POST['state'] == "AR"){echo "selected";}?>>Arkansas</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="statefilt" name="statefilt" onclick="" value="Submit" />
</form>
```